# Bind size and position of floating elements in AvalonDock with MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, avalondock

I am trying to bind the `Width` and `Height` properties of the floating (undocked) documents in `AvalonDock`. I am using `MVVM` pattern.
I want to save the properties (together with the docking state and the position of the window, if undocked) and be able to restore them. Using a `XmlLayoutSerializer` is not an option because this requires a reference to the docking manager which is not allowed in the ViewModel.

This is the XAML code:

```
<avalonDock:DockingManager DocumentsSource="{Binding Files}"
                           ActiveContent="{Binding ActiveDocument, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <avalonDock:DockingManager.LayoutItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type avalonDock:LayoutDocumentItem}">
            <Setter Property="Title" Value="{Binding Model.Title}"/>
            <Setter Property="CanClose" Value="False" />
            <Setter Property="CanFloat" Value="True" />
        </Style>
    </avalonDock:DockingManager.LayoutItemContainerStyle>

    <avalonDock:LayoutRoot>
        <avalonDock:LayoutPanel>
            <avalonDock:LayoutDocumentPane>
            </avalonDock:LayoutDocumentPane>
        </avalonDock:LayoutPanel>
    </avalonDock:LayoutRoot>
```

The ViewModel:

```
private ObservableCollection<PaneViewModel> m_readonyFiles;
public ObservableCollection<PaneViewModel> Files
{
    get { return m_readonyFiles ?? (m_readonyFiles = 
             new ObservableCollection<PaneViewModel>()); }
}

private PaneViewModel _activeDocument = null;
public PaneViewModel ActiveDocument
{
    get { return _activeDocument; }
    set
    {
        if (_activeDocument != value)
        {
            _activeDocument = value;

            RaisePropertyChanged("ActiveDocument");
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to set a binding in the style of `LayoutDocumentItem` but the setter never gets called:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type avalonDock:LayoutDocumentItem}">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="{Binding ActiveDocument.CurrentWidth, Mode=TwoWay}"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="{Binding ActiveDocument.CurrentHeigth, Mode=TwoWay}"></Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

How can I save and restore the size and position of the floating documents without violating the MVVM pattern?

---

Solution Update >>>

I finally solved my problem with an idea from one of the articles @Sheridan linked to in his answer. I created a messenger that handles communication between my ViewModel and the CodeBehind of the View. There I get position and size of the documents and send them back to ViewModel. To restore, I use a `ILayoutUpdateStrategy` and in the function `AfterInsertDocument`, I restore the states.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In WPF, we manipulate *data elements* rather than *UI elements*. So instead of attempting to save UI controls, along with their ridiculous amounts of properties, just save the relevant property values. Normally, the best way to do this is to declare a custom class that contains the required property types and values.

However, in the case of AvalonDock, there is a handy extension function of the `DockingManager` object that takes care of this for you:

```
/// <summary>
/// Event raised when the window is about to close.
/// </summary>
private void Window_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    ...

    //
    // When the window is closing, save AvalonDock layout to a file.
    //
    avalonDockHost.DockingManager.SaveLayout(LayoutFileName);
}
```

...

```
/// <summary>
/// Event raised when AvalonDock has loaded.
/// </summary>
private void avalonDockHost_AvalonDockLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(LayoutFileName))
    {
        //
        // If there is already a saved layout file, restore AvalonDock layout from it.
        //
        avalonDockHost.DockingManager.RestoreLayout(LayoutFileName);
    }
    else
    {
        //
        // ... no previously saved layout exists, need to load default layout ...
        //
    }
}
```

These examples were taken from the [AvalonDock and MVVM](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/239342/AvalonDock-and-MVVM) page on Code Project, which you may find interesting for other reasons too. For further help on the topic, please refer to the [Loading/Saving AvalonDock Layouts at Start-up/Shut-Down](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/719143/AvalonDock-Tutorial-Part-Load-Save-Layout) page on Code Project, or the [Save/Load Layout & Content](http://avalondock.codeplex.com/discussions/428711) and [AvalonDock 2.0 getting started guide PART 2](https://avalondock.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=AvalonDock%202.0%20Getting%20Start%20Guide%20PART%202) pages on the AvalonDock section of CodePlex.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The DockingManager seems to have no function 'SaveLayout'. I'm using version 2.0.2000.0

Comment: If you had actually taken the time to read the linked articles, then you would have read that it is a behaviour, or extension method, that you have to define. Apologies for calling it 'built-in'.

Comment: I finally solved my problem with an idea from one of the articles you linked in the answer. I created a messenger that handles communication between my ViewModel and the CodeBehind of the View. There I get position and size of the documents and send them back to ViewModel. To restore, I use a 'ILayoutUpdateStrategy' and in the function 'AfterInsertDocument' I restore the states.

Comment: Thanks for updating... I've added your comment into your question where it will be more easily seen.